# create records from bootstrap.test.js while testing sails js with mocha

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

While testing sails app with mocha, I want to create some users, so that I can test for login.
According to the documentation of Sails, we can write that logic in
bootstrap.test.js in before() function.
But the below code is not creating the user from bootstrap.test.js.
I am getting undefined result.
Because of which login test is getting failed.

### bootstrap.test.js

```
var sails = require('sails');

before(function(done) {

  // Increase the Mocha timeout so that Sails has enough time to lift.
  this.timeout(5000);

  sails.lift({
    // configuration for testing purposes
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) return done(err);

    // as per documentation we must write that logic here,
    // but it is unable to create the users (user_details is the model class).


user_details.create(
                [{
                    id:1,
                    email: "vishal@gmail.com",
                    password: "vishal",
                    userType:'ADMIN' 
                }]
            ).exec(function createCB(err, user) {
                logger.info('Created User');
            });
    done(err, sails);
  });
});


after(function(done) {
  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);

});
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot, I got the below solution.This will create the records before actual testing starts.

```
var sails = require('sails');
var _ = require('lodash');
require('ts-node/register');
var async = require("async");

global.chai = require('chai');
global.should = chai.should();

before(function (done) {

    this.timeout(10000);

    sails.lift({
        environment: 'test',
        log: {
            level: 'silent'
        },
        hooks: {
            session: false
        },
        models: {
            connection: 'unitTestConnection',
            migrate: 'drop'
        },
        connections: {
            unitTestConnection: {
                adapter: 'sails-mysql',
                host: 'localhost',
                user: 'root',
                password: 'password',
                database: 'ddn_db_dev',
                port: 3306
            }
        }
    }, function(){
        async.parallel({
                createTenants: function(cb){
                    // create tenants
                    tenant.create(
                        [{
                            id: 1,
                            name: "SAAS",
                            organization: "SAAS",
                            domain: "SAAS",
                            email: "geocloudinc@gmail.com",
                            tenantType: 'SAAS',
                            phone: '9848022338',
                            address: 'USA'
                        }]
                    ).exec(function createCB(err, user) {
                        logger.info('bootstrap.test.js From create tenant');
                        cb();
                    });
                }
            },
            function(err, results) {
                async.parallel({
                        createUsers: function(cb){
                            // create users
                            user_details.create(
                                [{
                                    id: 1,
                                    email: "sass_geocloudinc@gmail.com",
                                    passwordHash: "synchronize",
                                    userType: 'SAAS_ADMIN',
                                    fullName: 'SAAS Admin',
                                    timeZone: 'pst',
                                    tenantId: 1
                                }]
                            ).exec(function createCB(err, user) {
                                logger.info('bootstrap.test.js Create default Service Admin user');
                                cb();
                            });

                        }
                    },
                    function(err, results) {
                        done();
                    });
            });
    });
});

after(function (done) {
    if (sails && _.isFunction(sails.lower)) {
        sails.lower(done);
    }
});
```